# Numerical Multivariate Integration with respect to a Multivariate Gaussian

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I have the following likelihood which is basically the convolution between the product of m independent Poisson densities and a multivariate Gaussian density:

$L(\mathbf{y}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg(\Pi_{i=1}^{m}\dfrac{\exp\{y_i\mu_i-e^\mu_i\}}{y_i!}\bigg)(2\pi)^{-m/2}|\Sigma|^{-1/2}\exp\bigg\{-\dfrac{(\mathbf{\mu}-\mathbf{\mu_0})^{\top}\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{\mu}-\mathbf{\mu}_0)}{2}\bigg\}\mbox{d}\mathbf{\mu}$

where $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,\ldots,y_m)\in\Re^m$, $\mathbf{\mu}=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_m)\in\Re^m$, $\mathbf{\mu}_0\in\Re^m$ and $\Sigma$ is a $m$ by $m$ positive semi-definite matrix. Or equivalently, the likelihood can be expressed as

$L(\mathbf{y}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg(\Pi_{i=1}^{m}\mbox{Poisson}(y_i|\mu_i)\bigg)\mathcal{N}_m(\mathbf{\mu}|\mathbf{\mu}_0,\Sigma)\mbox{d}\mathbf{\mu}$

I have observed a bunch of $\mathbf{y}$'s and my goal is to estimate $\mathbf{\mu}_0$ and $\Sigma$. However, the main difficulty is that the likelihood is not in a closed form, but in an multivariate integration.

To my best knowledge there is no closed form solution to this integration, hence **I am seeking for a numerical method to approximate the integration**. The dimension $m$ is roughly around 30.

Any suggestion would be useful!

Many thanks!